# updating drupal schema

Tags: drupal

I have an install file in place which creates a table when the module is first enabled. Halfway into the use of the module, I want to update the table with an additional column I write the code for it as

```
'salary' => array(
  'description' => t('Salary: '),
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned'=> TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```

This goes within the schema definition. Now to add it to the database , I use the update function as

```
function test_update_6001(){
  $ret = array();
  $spec = array(

  'description' => t('Salary: '),
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned'=> TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,

  );
  db_add_field($ret,'info','salary',$spec);  //info is the tablename and salary is the column to be added

  return $ret;
  drupal_install_schema('stalker');
}
```

This is not updating the schema. Am i missing a step?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include it in the original hook_schema() function and not just in the update function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the `drupal_install_schema` after the return, but it's not the cause anyway. There's no error when you run the update.php script?

Comment: the error was the N which i was using it should be  function test_update_6100(){ $ret = array(); $spec = array(
   'description' => t('Client: '),
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'length' => '20',
   'not null' => TRUE, 
   ); db_add_field($ret,'info','client',$spec,$keys_new = array());return $ret; }